# How to retrieve view Count from Youtube using InputStream and Scanner

Tags: java, youtube, try-catch, inputstream, joptionpane

I am taking a minor course on java programming and I am working on an assignment where we are provided with URLs and we need to retrieve some specific data from the webpage's source code and post them on a JOptionPane. The problem I'm having is that after scanning, I don't know how to get the number from the source code:

Here's what I have thus far (It's incomplete but I just need a little help with how to retrieve the number of viewcount:

```
    try {

        URL url1 = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0");
        InputStream viewCount = url1.openStream();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(inTemp);
        String name = read.nextLine();
        String wanted = "watch-view-count ";    
        String noOfViews = null;

        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            if (name.contains(wanted)) {
                noOfViews = wanted; 
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


    String messageInHTML = "<html>Temperature: ";
    messageInHTML += "<li>Relative Humidity: " ;
    messageInHTML += "<li>Hang Seng Index: " ;
    messageInHTML += "<li>Gangnum Style View Count: " ;
    messageInHTML += "</html>";

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, messageInHTML, "BillBoard", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("User clicked OK");
    }
    if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("User clicked Cancel");
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the youtube api? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Cause the aim of our assignment is to practise using file I/O and URL classes for web-data processing.

Comment: So you want to extract the number from the given HTML-Line you found? Then I would use regular expressions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html